# Clipping text in a paragraph by the size of a table column

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I use iText 7. I have a table with two columns:

```
var table = new Table(new UnitValue[] { UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(40), UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(60) })
.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));
```

I create a cell and add a paragraph to them. Then I add this cell to the table in the first column.

I want the first column, which the width is 40%, keep this width. 
But this does not happen if I specify an overly large font in the paragraph and the text that is in it does not fit into the cell.

I don't want this behavior. I want that the text in the paragraph clipped.
How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, which iText 7 version exactly do you use? There have been major changes in the table handling in the course of the 7.0.x versions.

Comment: I use iText 7.1.2

Comment: Is it possible to share a small code sample that illustrates this issue?
I've tried replicating the situation but the width of the cell in my example stays at 40%. It simply grows vertically in order to fit the paragraph. Which seems like expected behavior to me.